# What is the function of Vm (Voltage max) in this closed-loop feedback?

Tags: feedback

Attached is the image of my project's closed-loop system. I need to describe each of the function based on the diagram. However I am unclear about the function of Vm in the closed-loop system and why it has to be divided by one? Can anyone clarify this? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Can you amplify the function of the system and what is each output?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what that project function block does?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be something like a voltage regulator. In this case, the purpose of block 1/Vm is to transform the voltage at the output of the controller block Gc (Vc) to a duty-cycle value d (between 0 and 1) to be applied in the Gp plant. This occurs by dividing that voltage by its maximum value Vm.

Comment: because the transfer function of a PWM for d(s) =0 to 1 would be the d(s)=Vc/Vm where Vm is the max voltage of some clock (s) which can be assumed to be operating at a fixed or variable rep. rate PFM or PWM of 1/T interval such that Vc(t) does not change much a short interval of 1/T so that output is just the variable duty cycle d(s)

Comment: Thanks so much! Really help for my viva presentation next week. Thank you again. Yup, actually this is just for the rough block diagram. I actually design a controller system with boost converter :) @ton

Comment: Boost converters more often use PFM rather than PWM just FYI @user132536 ok?